# What is "Standardizing variables" in the procedure of converting First Order Logic to CNF?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

What is meant by the step "Standardize variables" in the procedure of converting First Order Logic to CNF?
The 6 all steps can be listed as,

```
1. Elimination of implication
2. Move ¬ inwards
3. Standardize variables
4. Remove existential quantifier (skolemize)
5. Drop universal quantifiers
6. Distribute ∧ over ∨
```

but I can't understand clearly what is standerdizing variables? Can somebody explain with an example?

Answer (score 2):

See in Wiki : [CNF - Converting from first-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) :

> **2.Standardize variables** : For sentences like $(\forall xP(x)) \lor (\exists xQ(x))$ which use the same variable name twice, change the name of one of the variables. This avoids confusion later when dropping quantifiers.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Wiki has a very good explaination.